# NSUserDefaults returns custom objects from array in random manner

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsuserdefaults, custom-object

When I save array of product (which is a custom object) in `NSUserDefaults`, and retrieve array from `NSUserDefaults`, it returns random array. And when I check whether returned array contains  added product or not, it always fails. Here is my code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:@"MY_FAV_PROD"];
NSArray *myFavArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:myFavArray];

if(myFavArray.count || array.count) {

        if([array containsObject:self.product]) {

            [array removeObject:self.product];

            myFavArray = nil;
            myFavArray = [myFavArray copy];

            data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myFavArray];
            [defaults setObject:data forKey:@"MY_FAV_PROD"];
            [defaults synchronize];
            [self addButton:@"UnFilled"];

        }
        else {

            [array addObject:self.product];
            myFavArray = nil;
            myFavArray = [array copy];
            data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myFavArray];
            [defaults setObject:data forKey:@"MY_FAV_PROD"];
            [defaults synchronize];
            [self addButton:@"Filled"];

        }
}
else {

    NSArray *firstObj = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.product, nil];
     data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:firstObj];
    [defaults setObject:data forKey:@"MY_FAV_PROD"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [self addButton:@"Filled"];

}

data = [defaults objectForKey:@"MY_FAV_PROD"];
myFavArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
NSLog(@"%@",myFavArray);
```

Please help

Comment: what do you mean by random? can you show some example of the Array you saved compared to the Array you retrieved?

Comment: First time I store <FeaturedProduct: 0x15e2aea0> in nsuserdefaults and when I retrieve array from nsuserdefaults it gives me     "<FeaturedProduct: 0x15eae140>"

Comment: "0x15e2aea0" And "0x15eae140" display only memory address this is not a rendom

Comment: Describe your issue more detailed "it always fails". Also log your actual- and post your expected data.